# How to duplicate a running process?

Tags: linux

Platform: Linux

I studied `fork`, `posix_spawn`, `vfork`, `rfork/clone`, but none of them can solve this problem.

My goal is to create a process and the new process copys the memory of the specified process.

Is there a way to create a process by by specifying a existed PID?

Comment: Short answer, No. The OS is responsible for handling program startup requests and reserving memory for it, and as part of the process associating a process ID. There isn't a way to specify what PID you want to create or copy. `strace` can attach to an existing PID to follow its execution, but that is about as close as you can come. Your question appears to be an *XY Problem*. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why do you want to copy the memory of the process?  Would this include things like keys that are in memory?  Stack frames, so the new process would effectively be a duplicate of the old one including how it's executing?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My real problem is tracing the real-time function calls of a process（or get each push and eject of Stack）, but i I didn't find the right way.  i

Comment: @StephenNewell My real problem is tracing the real-time function calls of a process（or get each push and eject of Stack）, but i I didn't find the right way.  i

Comment: @ANTHONY - That's an entirely different problem, so I'd suggest you ask it directly.

Comment: @ANTHONY - then using `strace` will allow you to attach to a running process giving the PID and watch when each function call is made. E.g., as root, `strace -p PID` where `PID` is the process ID to connect to. You can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to separate files to capture the output as well.